# Unity 3D add gravity on a long cube to attract the player from 4 sides

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am making a 3D platform game on unity. The player should be able to stand on every side of the cube. I have tried to add gravity manually from searching through the internet. What i was able to make is that the cube has gravity in the center so the player is always being attracted to go to the center.

Suppose, the cube is 50m long and 1m in Y and 1m in Z. The player tends to go to 25m in x because of the center gravity. What i need to make is that, no matter where the player is in x co-ordinate, it will only be attracted to the y value. The player should be able to stand on any side and the platform will move accordingly.
For better explanation, there's a drawing i have made.
[image: Player standing on a cube]

Comment: the player will strictly stay at the middle of each side, when switching side, it will immediately change the platform side in a way that the player will always stand above the platform

Comment: rotate the cube not gravity?

Comment: I can actually rotate the cube without adding physics but i was thinking of adding gravity so that the player can jump in a realistic manner.

Comment: yes @ScottChamberlain there will be other agents. That's another reason of adding gravity :)

Comment: It is not exactly clear, are you wanting the player to be attracted to the 25m mark or are you being attracted to the 25m mark and you don't want that to happen.

Comment: The second one. if i add gravity to (1x1x1)m cube, the player stands on the middle. But if i make the cube bigger in any co-ordinate, the player gets attracted to the middle. I want the player to stand on each-side like there's equal gravity on the surface.

Comment: You need to figure out which face the player is closest to, and make that face "down."  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rlgO.png

Comment: how do i acquire this? a detailed explanation would be great! :) @Draco18s

Comment: You need to calculate from the center to the corners and figure out which side of the line the player is on. If you're only concerned with 4 sides, it'll be easier.